# WPF Unusual Selection Highlighting in Design View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Good afternoon everyone, I feel kind of silly asking this but I've been digging around and can't find a reason why this is happening.  I think it is either some global style I have set or maybe some bug in how visual studio is presenting design view.

Now I have set global styles in App.xaml and after tinkering around with them I've been unable to figure out what is making the selection boxes for design mouse clicks be outside of the displayed GUI.

I did add a GroupBox style that I'm using for a custom control and perhaps that is where the problem is.  I admit I'm not the sharpest at WPF and would like to know if I have just done something dumb or if its a VS issue.  I've also included the contents of App.xml below the pictures.

Thanks for your time in advance!

![enter image description here

[image]

```
<Application
x:Class="EngineeringLabUi.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

<!--
So this is the root styles that will be aplied to every control of the target types declared here.
These settings can be overriden at anytime but any new instance of one of these controls will
inherit these first.
-->

<!--Padding represents the amount of inner space an element has, while the margin is whitespace available surrounding an element. It's not possible to set padding to auto padding. However, you can use automatic settings for margins.-->
<Application.Resources>
    <!--#region buttonStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion buttonStyle-->
    <!--#region ScrollViewer-->
    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,1" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion ScrollViewer-->
    <!--#region RadioButton-->
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion RadioButton-->
    <!--#region borderStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6" />
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="100" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion borderStyle-->
    <!--#region comboBoxStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,-5,5" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <!--< debug />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />-->
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion comboBoxStyle-->
    <!--#region labelStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion labelStyle-->
    <!--#region textBlockStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion textBlockStyle-->
    <!--#region groupBoxStyle-->
    <Style x:Key="GroupBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D5DFE5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                    <!--  turn off gridlines for demo, good for designing  -->
                    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border
                            x:Name="Header"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Padding="3,1,3,0">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion groupBoxStyle-->
    <!--#region checkBoxStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <!--< debug />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />-->
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion checkBoxStyle-->
    <!--#region ellipseStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion ellipseStyle-->
    <!--#region tabControltyle-->
    <Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion tabControltyle-->
    <!--#region tabItemStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion tabItemStyle-->
    <!--#region menuItemStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <!--< debug />-->
        <!--<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF020202" />-->
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion menuItemStyle-->
    <!--#region flowDocumentStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="FlowDocument">
        <Setter Property="ColumnRuleBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="ColumnRuleWidth" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="IsColumnWidthFlexible" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="PageWidth" Value="auto" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion flowDocumentStyle-->
    <!--#region gridStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
        <!--<Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="700" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1400" />-->
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5" />
        <Setter Property="ShowGridLines" Value="True" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion gridStyle-->
    <!--#region richTextBoxStyle-->
    <Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="500" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="700" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="500" />
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1000" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="auto" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
    <!--#endregion richTextBoxStyle-->
</Application.Resources>
```

**Update**

I think there might be an issue with my MainWindow definition or how I'm binding control width / height.  I'm including some more detail regarding that definition and usage below:

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window
x:Class="EngineeringLabUi.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:bh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:io="clr-namespace:System.IO.Ports;assembly=System"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:myTypes="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi.CustomTypes"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi.ViewModels"
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
x:Name="engLabUiWindow"
Width="auto"
Height="auto"
MinWidth="500"
MinHeight="500"
MaxHeight="750"
d:DesignHeight="589.382"
Icon="/archer_logo.ico"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
ShowInTaskbar="{Binding ShowInTaskbar}"
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
WindowState="{Binding WindowState}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

*Example of some bindings within this file (all grids are bound this way):*

```
<Grid x:Name="AppGrid" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight}">
<Grid x:Name="appConformTabGrid" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight}"/>
```

Comment: The pictures are very small. What version of VS?

Comment: Try click on that borders and check at properties block what is it. Looks like it is controls, just margined too far away out of window bounds

Comment: I mean something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy0Op.png

Comment: @JimFoye I've updated the picture to a larger one.  I'm using VS 2022 Community

Comment: @Auditive I've went through and checked margins and paddings because that is what I thought might be doing it.  I wonder if it might have something to do with my MainWindow.xaml definitions for the height and width?  And yes the image you shared describes what I'm seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of solving UI-related problems is by checking the UI tree. Try to rerun your app and click this button

[image].

It will bring you to the live visual tree and you can easily locate the control which is behaving wildly.

Comment: Haiming, Thanks for the info.  I have been using the XAML live viewer and selecting the to show the control under cursor and everything lines up.  Since this is happening when not running I didn't think that would be useful but I will give it a go

Comment: @MichaelRiley, thanks for the upvote. Did you solve it in the end? Did it only happen in the Designer or appear when you run it? Sometimes the XAML designer may have some conflicts with your UI. If it happens in both situations please let me know.